# Plesk disk usage Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, plesk

I have gotten a message saying I am taking up to much space on the server. It says I am 2MB over. I deleted almost 500MB of files not being used and I still am getting the same error in Plesk.
I know that a reconfiguration in server should be resolve this.
How will i do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Plesk is updating the disk usages stat through statistics.exe file. You can update it now with **%plesk_bin%statistics.exe**

Check this : http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-win-cli/index.htm?fileName=44810.htm